# same coordinates yield different results in Nominatim and MapQuest

Tags: geocoding, openstreetmap, reverse-geocoding, mapquest, nominatim

According to [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) and [MapQuest](http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/), the following end-points should provide the same data:

- Nominatim: http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse
- MapQuest: http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/reverse

In fact

> The Nominatim Search Service is similar to our MapQuest Search Service with its simple interface and powerful capabilities, but instead **relies solely on data contributed to OpenStreetMap**.

Therefore I would expect the two services to provide the same data, nevertheless the following query for the same coordinates (41.904163, 12.485597) yields different results:

- Nominatim: http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat=41.904163&lon=12.485597&addressdetails=1&format=xml&zoom=18
- MapQuest: http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/reverse.php?lat=41.904163&lon=12.485597&addressdetails=1&format=xml&zoom=18

Results:

- Nominatim: Via Francesco Crispi
- MapQuest: Via Gregoriana

Why?

**NOTE**: as of 12.44 PM UTC (July 1st, 2013) OSM is returning the same results as MapQuest. There are a couple of related discussions on GitHub:

- [Issue 66](https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim/issues/66)
- [Issue 67](https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim/issues/67)

Comment: Looks like a bug in the latest nominatim code. I've just issued a [bug report](https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim/issues/66).

Comment: As of now, OSM is returning the same results as MapQuest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Nominatim, which is going to be fixed:

> Nominatim was no longer searching for objects below street level (house numbers, POIs, etc.) due to this commit. It only concerned the instance on osm.org.

See issue #66 on GitHub: https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim/issues/66